# seperate selected item from column and make it different column

Tags: python, pandas

currenly this data is having states and region in one single column and i want to separate it
I want to covert and clean this data in states and regions different rows
This is the data i want to convert and clean

```
    Alabama[edit]
0   Auburn (Auburn University)[1]
1   Florence (University of North Alabama)
2   Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]
3   Livingston (University of West Alabama)[2]
4   Montevallo (University of Montevallo)[2]
5   Troy (Troy University)[2]
6   Tuscaloosa (University of Alabama, Stillman Co...
7   Tuskegee (Tuskegee University)[5]
8   Alaska[edit]
9   Fairbanks (University of Alaska Fairbanks)[2]
10  Arizona[edit]
11  Flagstaff (Northern Arizona University)[6]
12  Tempe (Arizona State University)
13  Tucson (University of Arizona)
14  Arkansas[edit]
15  Arkadelphia (Henderson State University, Ouach...
16  Conway (Central Baptist College, Hendrix Colle...
17  Fayetteville (University of Arkansas)[7]
18  Jonesboro (Arkansas State University)[8]
19  Magnolia (Southern Arkansas University)[2]
```

this is how i want data

```
    State   RegionName
0   Alabama     Auburn
1   Alabama     Florence
2   Alabama     Jacksonville
3   Alabama     Livingston
4   Alabama     Montevallo
5   Alabama     Troy
6   Alabama     Tuscaloosa
7   Alabama     Tuskegee
8   Alaska  Fairbanks
9   Arizona     Flagstaff
10  Arizona     Tempe
11  Arizona     Tucson
12  Arkansas    Arkadelphia
13  Arkansas    Conway
14  Arkansas    Fayetteville
15  Arkansas    Jonesboro
16  Arkansas    Magnolia
17  Arkansas    Monticello
18  Arkansas    Russellville
19  Arkansas    Searcy
```

Answer (score 0):

```
series = pd.Series(['Alabama[edit]',
'Auburn (Auburn University)[1]',
'Florence (University of North Alabama)',
'Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]',
'Livingston (University of West Alabama)[2]',
'Montevallo (University of Montevallo)[2]',
'Troy (Troy University)[2]',
'Tuscaloosa (University of Alabama, Stillman Co...)',
'Tuskegee (Tuskegee University)[5]',
'Alaska[edit]',
'Fairbanks (University of Alaska Fairbanks)[2]',
'Arizona[edit]',
'Flagstaff (Northern Arizona University)[6]',
'Tempe (Arizona State University)',
'Tucson (University of Arizona)',
'Arkansas[edit]',
'Arkadelphia (Henderson State University, Ouach...)',
'Conway (Central Baptist College, Hendrix Colle...)',
'Fayetteville (University of Arkansas)[7]',
'Jonesboro (Arkansas State University)[8]',
'Magnolia (Southern Arkansas University)[2]'])

cleaned = series.apply(lambda x: str(x).split('(')[0])
id_state = cleaned.str.contains(r'edit').cumsum()-1
map_state = dict(enumerate(cleaned.loc[cleaned.str.contains(r'edit')].apply(lambda x: str(x).split('[')[0])))
id_state = [map_state[i] for i in id_state]

df = pd.DataFrame({'State':id_state, 'RegionName':cleaned})
df = df.loc[~cleaned.str.contains(r'edit')]
df
```

result:

[image]